# How to update label multiple times after pressing button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I have a process that once you click the button, you will get updates of where you are in the process.  (Processing 1 of 11)

I have tried using a textbox as well as a label to hold the text inside an UpdatePanel, but I cannot seem to get either to update as the process moves along.

It is not updating .  Here is my code.

```
    <div class="w3-row-padding  w3-center w3-mobile">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>            

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Create Life Budget" CssClass="w3-button w3-black" Font-Bold="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                <br />
                <br />                    
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtProgress" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" Width="300px">In Progress ...</asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

Protected Sub cmdSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    divBudgetList.Visible = False
    divCreateBudget.Visible = True
    divReports.Visible = True
    Master.HideMsg()
    CreateLifeBudget()
End Sub

Public Sub CreateLifeBudget()    
    Dim iProgress As Long
    Dim iProgressMax As Long = 11

    iProgress = 1
    txtProgress.Text = "Processing " & iProgress & " of " & iProgressMax

    .... Other Code

    iProgress = 1
    txtProgress.Text = "Processing " & iProgress & " of " & iProgressMax

    .... Other Code

    txtProgress.Text = "Processing has completed"

End Sub
```

I have tried with the updatemode as both conditional as well as Always.
I have added the Trigger as well.

Nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you set `iProgress = 1 directly before setting the .Text, you will always show 1 of 11.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, doing it you way you cannot get status updates as the method will run in the click event before anything is returned to the client.

The only way i know to do this (and it's how I do it) is to run the CreateLifeBudget task in a separate thread and then return to the client immediately, kicking off a client side timer that calls a page method or ajax call to get the status of the long running task and updating the client from there.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Do you have sample code that can show me what you are talking about?  I haven't done threads at all and I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I haven't had a chance to look at this thoroughly.  I did try, but I am not getting this to work.  I will use your example once I have a chance to get back to testing this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll try and here's a simplified solution I just knocked up based on what we do elsewhere.

Fist of all you need your button and something to show the progress (you could actually show the progress on the button but that's semantics):

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="u" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uxStartTaskBtn" Text="Start Task" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="uxStartTaskBtn_Click" />
                <span id="progress"></span>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then you need a bit of javascript to do the progress checking:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var longRunningTaskMonitorTimer = null;
    function kickOffLongRunningTaskMonitor() {
        longRunningTaskMonitorTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
            window.PageMethods.getLongRunningTaskProgress(function (percentComplete) {
                document.getElementById("progress").innerText = "Task is " + percentComplete + " percent complete";
                if (percentComplete == 100) {
                    window.clearInterval(longRunningTaskMonitorTimer);
                    window.alert("Task Complete");
                }
            });
        }, 800);
    }
</script>``
```

This function will be called when the button is clicked and will repeatedly poll for updated progress until the task has finished running, there's no error checking so you'll need to put it in, don't want to poll indefinitely if the task has failed!

In your back end page you'll need a class to run the task in a thread and also somewhere to store a reference to the current task, and a page method that the JS calls to get the progress:
''
    public partial class LongRunningTaskPage : System.Web.UI.Page {

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Store a reference to the current task
    /// </summary>
    private static LongRunningTask CurrentTask {
        get {
            return (LongRunningTask)HttpContext.Current.Session["ct"];
        }
        set {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ct"] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the start button is clicked, starts the task and sends back
    /// some JS to the page to kick off the poller
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void uxStartTaskBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Create and start the task
        CurrentTask = new LongRunningTask();
        CurrentTask.Start();
        // This will kick off the javascript timer to check the progress of the long runnig task periodically
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "longRunningTask", "kickOffLongRunningTaskMonitor();", true);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method called from JS to get the progress of the current task
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [WebMethod]
    public static int getLongRunningTaskProgress() {
        return CurrentTask.CurrentProgress;
    }

    // This class represents a unit of work to do that takes a long time
    private class LongRunningTask {
        public int CurrentProgress { get; set; }
        public void Start() {
            var t = new Thread(() => DoWork());
            t.Start();
        }

        public void DoWork() {
            // This is where you do your work updating progress as applicable
            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                CurrentProgress = i;
                Thread.Sleep(200);  // Simlulate some long task
            }
        }

    }
}''
```

The code is very simple as it has no error handling so you will need to add that, it s possible to do the whole thing using page methods only but in my case I needed access to session variables so had to do it this way.  I'm sure there are other ways of achieving the same thing, you don't need to use page methods you could use Ajax calls but that's what we use.

Also this is c#, I see your code is VB, you should be able to transpose it easy enough.

Hope this points you in the right direction.